# How to add an element in the end of an array

Tags: c++

Could you help How to add an element in the end of an array as many times as we input, for instance:

```
2
-1 2 
10 5       -1 2 10 10 10 10 10
```

It is what I did but it went wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> arr(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    int x, k;
    cin >> x >> k;
    for (int i = 0; i < n+k; i++)
        arr.resize(arr.size()+1, x);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you mean at least for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        arr.resize(arr.size()+1, x); Though you could call the method resize only one time like arr.resize(arr.size()+k, x);

Comment: Ooh, thanks) it was easier than I thought

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) arr.push_back(x);
```

This will add the value `x` `k` times to the `vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> arr(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    int x, k;
    cin >> x >> k;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) arr.push_back(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fjGPPWjaz

or you could use the `resize` function instead (without the loop):

```
arr.resize(arr.size()+k, x);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hbxWGza53

Comment: Thank you very much:) It's clear to me already